# Give NSWindow a background image

Tags: cocoa

Ok, so I've created an image in Photoshop that will align with the buttons on my app, and now I'd like to make it the background image of my window so that the characters on the image will correspond to the keys on my app (a small calculator demo app I've been working on)

Basically, instead of giving buttons Text like 1,2,3,4, etc. I've made a 3x3 map with numbers of a different font just because it will look pretty

What I'm having difficulty with now is that I can't seem to make the image the background of my window.

I created an NSImageView and I dragged the image file onto it, so I can see it now, but I can't make it the background.

Do I need to subclass the NSImageView or is there some simple method?

I'm using XCode 4, btw

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you should be able to do something like:

```
[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]]];
```

Comment: Where is this supposed to go? I tried my AppDelegate and `window` is undefined. substituting `window` with `[self window]` got the app to compile and run, but nothing happened.

Comment: This is not properly setting my background image, I mean the image is not fitting to my window frame, lot of space unused. How to go about this, thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

This is something that a layer-backed window would be good at:

```
[[window contentView] setWantsLayer:YES];
[[window contentView] layer].contents = myImage;
```

I think you stand a better chance of getting this to resize sensibly (assuming you need to) than with a pattern color.

Comment: Works great, however it does not cover the title bar area. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: The title bar isn't part of the window's `contentView`; if you want to draw on top of that too, you are probably looking at fully custom window drawing: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html and I'm pretty sure there's a question or two here on SO about it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you more options -- you should be able to `[window setContentView:myImageView]`.  In the .xib file you'd want to add your buttons etc. as subviews of the image view.
I don't necessarily recommend this approach, but it's something to think about.

Comment: It's a good thought -- you can even just change the class of the content view in the IB inspector -- but I don't think there's any way to set up an image view (either IK or NS) with subviews in IB, which means you'd have to move them all around in code.

Comment: Yes, but it's easier than it sounds -- you can set up a "view-hosting view" in IB, and then in code you can add just *that* view as subview to the ImageView.

Comment: @Josh Caswell then it's a (relatively simple) matter of getting the resizing masks correct (for the subviews of the "hosting view").

Comment: @Richard - how does one set up a 'view-hosting view' ? I've looked around and can't find such an object in IB.

Comment: @TotalCocoaNewb drag a "Custom View" NSView from the Library, and then add your buttons, text fields, etc. as its subviews.