# Using NSImage as patterned/repeated background in NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nsimage

I want to display NSImage as repeated background in NSWindow. I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435560/give-nswindow-a-background-image) code:

```
_window.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

The problem arises on resizing, because only the new area (at the bottom and the right) of the window is redisplayed and the background origin is in the bottom-left corner. That results in image gliching:
[image: window example]

Current workaround is to redisplay window on resize:

```
_window.delegate = self;
...
- (void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification {
  [_window display];
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to automatically display all background on resizing (i.e. without usign `windowDidResize:`)?
2. Can background origin be changed to upper-left correr (so that new area on resizing will seamlessly continue existing one)?

Comment: In regards to point 2, I don't think the issue is the origin changing. The issue is that the image is being scaled as the window grows.

Comment: The image is repositioned (relatively to lower-left corner), not scaled.

Comment: Here, I've updated the image to better demonstrate point 2.